# Android Simulator Default Zoomed In

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I just downloaded Android Studio and the simulator for some reason is zoomed in very far or has enormous text. I've tried everything on the right-hand bar to handle this and there are no menu bar options. How can I resolve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same exact problem at first. After I had opened my project in Android Studio, the IDE installed a bunch of other libraries and tools; in turn priming the environment. To note, this was all after a fresh install of Android Studio. After the supplemental install, I then started the emulator from the AVD Manager from within the IDE. Afterwards, whenever I ran the emulator again I had experienced zero issues like this. I understand some of this sounds anecdotal but it seems that the Android Studio IDE helped sort this out for me at least.

I would also like to note that, if you experienced any warnings or errors when executing the simulator, it may also be an issue originating from the emulator's environment itself. Possibly tweaking some of the settings on the emulator could also help (i.e., memory/storage capacity).